# How to select a SKRoute on a single tap in iphone sdk

Tags: skmaps

I'm working in SKMaps. I'm new to maps. Please give me idea to highlight a route when tapping anywhere on the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current SDK is not supporting this.

You can highlight the route (if this would be a good option for you) via a GPX track or a polyline.
Here you'll find how to deal this on [iOS](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec10). The demo projects contains also examples of both GPX track drawing and polylines/polygons: http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download